# Javascript - Show 18 images and then stop

Tags: javascript, loops, background

What I'm trying to do is to change a background image 17 times, and then stop. When the user opens a new page, the same thing should happen, load 17 images and stop. The thing is, I don't know much about javascipt (I will learn I promise.) I found a script, it works, but I geuss I have to add a break. I tried but didn't succeed. Here's the code:

```
var imgArr = new Array(
    // relative paths of images
    'images/bgshow/1.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/2.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/3.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/4.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/5.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/6.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/7.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/8.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/9.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/10.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/11.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/12.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/13.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/14.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/15.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/16.jpg',
    'images/bgshow/17.jpg'
);

var preloadArr = new Array();
var i;

/* preload images */
for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    preloadArr[i] = new Image();
    preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
}

var currImg = 1;
var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 150);

/* image rotator */
function changeImg() {
    $('#page-wrap').animate({opacity: 0}, 0, function() {
        $(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') top center no-repeat');
    }).animate({opacity: 1}, 0);
}
```

Would appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script will keep changing images every `150ms`, due to the `setInterval(changeImg, 150)` call. Thus, to stop it, you need to clear the interval when you are done changing all your images. This can be done at the end of your `changeImg` function, add the following;

```
function changeImg() {
  // animation code...
  if (currImg == preloadArr.length) {
    clearInterval(intID);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct except for the fact that the current script will never hit currImg == 17, because of the line immediately prior currImg++%preloadArr.length.  I'd suggest putting your check BEFORE the animation code, checking for 16 and returning after you clear the interval

Comment: @Jando, be sure to accept the answer if it is correct.  Also, does that script skip over some images?  The first time changeImg() is called currImg will be changed to 2 which the background will then be changed to?

Comment: No the script is not supposed to skip any images. It means that I can delete currImg()?

Answer (score 0):

if (`currImg == preloadArr.length`) run not `clearInterval(intID);` always `currImg == 0;`

In fact; `currImg++` add Before or "`if (currImg++ == preloadArr.length)`"

```
function changeImg() {
    // animation code...
    if (currImg++ == preloadArr.length) {
        clearInterval(intID);
    }
}
```